# How to get a big-O, Big-Ω and big-Θ for this function?

Tags: math, big-o

I have a function f(n) defined as follows:

> f(n) = (n-1)(n+1)lg(n+5)/(n+3)

Here, lg is log<sub>2</sub>. I'd like to determine the big-O, big-Ω, and big-Θ values for this function. How would I go about approaching this?

Thanks!

Comment: big-O and big-omega are needed for estimation. If you have precise function dependence - why ask this? Your estimation _is your function_.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe i ask the question wrong. The question is ask me to give a big O , Big Ω and big θ in f(n). and I don't know how to give.

Comment: Ok, then first though: your big-O will be `O(n)=n^2`, big-omega will be `W(n)=n` and big-theta will be `T(n)=n log(n)`. I hope if you'll look into math limit definitions and big-O/omega/theta notation, you'll find why it is so.

Comment: Could you explain why big theta will be nlog(n)? I have read the definition of big-theta but i still not understand it. Thank You

Comment: Because it's grows speed will be exactly same as your function (not bigger, not lesser, but the same). Why it is so? Again: read math limit definition.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start off by simplifying your expression:

> f(n) = (n-1)(n+1)lg(n+5)/(n+3)
>
> = ((n<sup>2</sup> - 1) lg (n + 5)) / (n + 3)

For now, let's pretend that the additive constants are there.  If we delete those constants, we get this function g(n):

> g(n) = n<sup>2</sup> lg n / n = n lg n

Since we don't expect those constants to make all that much of a difference in the long term, it's reasonable to venture a guess that this function is Θ(n log n). We can prove this by taking the limit of f(n) / n log n as n tends toward infinity. If we get back a nonzero finite value, then we known that f(n) = Θ(n log n).

So let's try it!

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> f(n) / n log n
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (((n<sup>2</sup> - 1) lg (n + 5)) / (n + 3)) / n lg n
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> ((n<sup>2</sup> - 1) lg (n + 5)) / n lg n (n + 3)
>
> = (lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (n<sup>2</sup> - 1) / n(n+3)) (lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (lg (n + 5) / lg n)
>
> = (lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (n<sup>2</sup> - 1) / (n<sup>2</sup> + n)) (lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (lg (n + 5) / lg n)

Both of these limits are degenerate forms of type ∞ / ∞, so we can use l'Hopital's rule and replace each with its derivative:

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (n<sup>2</sup> - 1) / (n<sup>2</sup> + n)
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (2n / 2n + 1)
>
> = 1

and

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> lg (n + 5) / lg n
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (1 / (n+5)) / (1 / n)
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (n / (n+5))
>
> = 1

Therefore, we get

> (lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (n<sup>2</sup> - 1) / (n<sup>2</sup> + n)) (lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (lg (n + 5) / lg n)
>
> = 1

Consequently, the ratio of f(n) / n lg n tends toward 1 as n goes to infinity, and so we have that f(n) = Θ(n log n), as required. Because of this, we also get that f(n) = O(n log n) and f(n) = Ω(n log n).  We also have that f(n) ~ n log n, which is a much stronger claim.

Hope this helps!